# AWS How to push file in folder inside S3 bucket using local stack

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, cloud, bucket, localstack

I am using below code to push file in s3 bucket of AWS, It's working fine

```
       `var folderPath = <Folder Name>;
        string fileName = <File name with path>; // test.json
        var bucketKey = folderPath + fileName;

        using var stream = domainItemErrorMessage.Message.ToStream();
        var putObjectRequest = new S3BucketItem
        {
            BucketName = <BucketName>,
            Key = bucketKey,
            FileContent = stream
        };`
```

But when I tries to use same code for local stack, it's giving error as.

> Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist

But when I combine bucket name and folder name like and key separate its working fine on local stack

```
       `var folderPath = <Folder Name>;
        string fileName = <File name with path>; // test.json
        var bucketKey = fileName;

        using var stream = domainItemErrorMessage.Message.ToStream();
        var putObjectRequest = new S3BucketItem
        {
            BucketName = <BucketName>+"/"+folderPath,
            Key = bucketKey,
            FileContent = stream
        };`
```

but giving error on AWS s3 as

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Comment: Line 3 in both snippets of code is different.

Answer (score 0):

Your key should be constructed like `folderPath + "/" + fileName`. You're missing the "/" in the first code snippet. Do not alter the bucket name. I don't have a C# example, but using the Java SDK it looks like

```
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
        .key(folderPath + "/" + fileName)
        .contentType(multipartFile.getContentType())
        .contentLength(multipartFile.getSize())
        .build();
```

This works on both AWS and LocalStack.